# Send console data to flask App to display on the client

Tags: python, flask, ipython, gevent

I'm trying to use a javascript plotting library to plot data I calculated in the python console (IPython) using Numpy.

I was thinking of a design to accomplish this. I thought it should look something like this:

[image]

This means I'm using a Flask app to sent a server-side event to the client as soon as the data is ready in the IPython process.

1) Is this the right approach?

2) How can I send data from the console to my Flask app? I think I need to run the Flask App with gevent so I can listen to commands from the other python process?

3) How can I send the data using a server-side event to the client? I found some examples of server-side events but I don't see how they can sent arbitrary data. Example:

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

from flask import Flask, request, Response, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def event_stream():
    count = 0
    while True:
        gevent.sleep(2)
        yield 'data: %s\n\n' % count
        count += 1

@app.route('/my_event_source')
def sse_request():
    return Response(
            event_stream(),
            mimetype='text/event-stream')

@app.route('/')
def page():
    return render_template('sse.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8001), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

This example uses a predefined event_stream() function. I am looking for a way to send the data from the python console with a server-side event to the client.

Maybe there is another and better approach?

Comment: You might also want to look into [Vincent](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is designed for visualising Python data using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Is it `$ipython console`(zmq console) of the plain IPython terminal (`$ipython`) ?
Why not directly use the IPython Notebook ?

(Notebook, QT and zmq console can allow a 3rd program to listen for event published by the kernel).

Have a look at [IPEP 21 and current implementation proposal](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4195) which is bidirectional kernel<-> js communication.

Did you had a look at [bokeh from continuum](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/Bokeh) that seem to do almost what you want ?

(also IPython not iPython in the images, but this is a detail)